# How to add code to just before closing body tag

Tags: javascript, footer

How would I put the following code, for a certain shopping cart, just before the closing body tag in my WordPress site? In the footer? It seems to me that I would only want to call startcart() for product pages. Thanks very much.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
startcart()
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're just using a small script or other markup, you can hook a function to the `wp_footer` filter, which should be included in all properly-coded themes:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    startcart()
    </script>

<?php } );
```

---

However, if your JavaScript code is more substantial, or you wish to use built-in libraries such as jQuery, you should put the code in an external file and enqueue it properly using the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'myscript', // lowercase name of script
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', // url to script
    array( 'jquery' ), // libraries to use
    false, // version of script (false is WP version)
    true // load in footer (true) or head (false)? 
);
```

You can read more about how to use the `wp_enqueue_script()` function in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

---

If you need more help, please post a comment below.